# Random Variable

Tags: mathematical-statistics, random-variable

Three components are randomly sampled, one at a
time, from a large lot. As each component is selected,
it is tested. If it passes the test, a success (S) occurs; if
it fails the test, a failure (F) occurs.
Assume that 80%
of the components in the lot will succeed in passing the
test. Let X represent the number of successes among
the three sampled components.

What are the possible values for X? And There Probabilities ?

Comment: This sounds like a homework/self-study problem. Please add the self-study tag and your thoughts on the problem. See http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As with a lot of statistical questions, the phrase "from a large lot" implies that the population you are drawing samples from is sufficiently large such that sampling without replacement will not change the probability of a success, i.e. the distribution of the sum of individual Bernoulli trials, each with probability of success 0.8, is a Binomial distribution with the same success parameter and n equal to the number of samples taken. That is
$$Y_i \sim Bernoulli(p = 0.8)$$
so that
$$ 
Y_i = \begin{cases}
 1, \;\ Pr(0.8) \\ 
 0, \;\ Pr(0.2)
\end{cases} \\ 
$$
and
$$
X = \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i \;\ \Rightarrow X \sim Binomial(n=3,p=0.8)
$$
where
$$
Pr(X = x) = \binom{3}{x}(0.8)^{x}(0.2)^{3-x}
$$
Therefore
$$Pr(X = 0) = (0.2)^{3} = 0.008$$
$$Pr(X = 1) = 3(0.8)(0.2)^{2} = 0.096$$
$$Pr(X = 2) = 3(0.8)^{2}(0.2) = 0.384$$
$$Pr(X = 3) = (0.8)^{3} = 0.512$$